# regex to extract substring for special cases

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a scenario where i want to extract some substring based on following condition.

1. search for any pattern myvalue=123& , extract myvalue=123
2. If the "myvalue" present at end of the line without "&", extract myvalue=123

for ex:

```
The string is abcdmyvalue=123&xyz => the it should return  myvalue=123
The string is abcdmyvalue=123 => the it should return  myvalue=123
```

for first scenario it is working for me with following regex - myvalue=*(.*?(?=[&,""]))
I am looking for how to modify this regex to include my second scenario as well. I am using https://regex101.com/  to test this.
Thanks in Advace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes about the pattern that you tried

- if you want to only match, you can omit the capture group
- `e*` matches 0+ times an `e` char
- the part `.*?(?=[&,""])`  matches as least chars until it can assert eiter `&` `,` or `"` to the right, so the positive lookahead expects a single char to the right to be present

You could shorten the pattern to a match only, using a negated character class that matches 0+ times any character except a whitespace char or `&`

```
myvalue=[^&\s]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/akhkhh/1)

Comment: Thanks, this looks fine. but this will not capture only first occurrence of the match. for ex: 123myvalue=123&abcdmyvalue=567&    - in this case its showing two matches. is there any way to find first occurrence ?

Comment: @BigD Yes, in that case you can use for example a capture group `^.*?(myvalue=[^&\s]*)` See https://regex101.com/r/gOZLXo/1

Comment: Thank you. its working.Accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function regex(data) {
var test = data.match(/=(.*)&/);
if (test === null) {
return data.split('=')[1]
} else {
return test[1]
}
}

console.log(regex('abcdmyvalue=123&3e')); //123
console.log(regex('abcdmyvalue=123')); //123
```

here is your working code if there is no & at end of string it will have null and will go else block there we can simply split the string and get the value, If & is present at the end of string then regex will simply extract the value between = and &

if you want to use existing regex then you can do it like that

```
var test = data1.match(/=(.*)&|=(.*)/)

const result = test[1] ? test[1] : test[2];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, am looking to modify my existing regex to include my second condition.

Comment: if you want to use existing regex then you can do it like that
var test = data1.match(/=(.*)&|=(.*)/)

    const result = test[1] ? test[1] : test[2];
    console.log(result);

Comment: Sorry, I am doing this test in https://regex101.com/  to use the regex for another purpose. I cant use these kind of coding.